# Correctly address Smart Contract storage address using web3js 1.0.0 library functions

Tags: solidity, web3js, storage, sha3, keccak

A short while ago, I found a fantastic Medium article [explaining Smart Contract storage](https://medium.com/aigang-network/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925).

The examples in this article have helped me to understand how to read a Smart Contract's storage values from the command line / console.

However, with the version [1.0.0 of web3js](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) going into Beta - and the [NPM version of web3js being installed by default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-eth) being the 1.0.0 Beta version, I thought that I would upgrade my code using the information from the aforementioned article to the new library.

**The problem is that I can't replicate the same behavior of web3.sha3 using the new version of the library; web3Utils.sha3**.

To clarify, here are some examples - starting with the output that I get from the stable, but pre-V1.0.0 web3.sha3 function and then from the new, Beta version of the web3js library:

To give you some context, the test is based on accessing the mappings data in this contrived Smart Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract StorageTest {
    mapping(address => uint256) public storedData;

    function addDataToMapping(address account, uint256 amount) public {
        storedData[account] = amount;
    }
}
```

The way that I determine how to access the mapping's data for the address `0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1` is by using the following pre-V1.0.0 web3js call:

```
web3.sha3("00000000000000000000000x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", {"encoding":"hex"})
```

This results in the hash value

```
0xbbf27a261d686d37ad5c6299e09a73a2a829c9c10eaf9c5c19e6ff2488e52f20
```

Now, if we simply port this over to the V1.0.0 library then the code looks like this:

```
web3Utils.sha3("00000000000000000000000x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", {"encoding":"hex"})
```

However, this results in the following (different) hash being output:

```
0x02d38ce98b8dae9d7cc32b64bb52580b4989cb56d07114b95037da4af5f500cf
```

I tried removing the `{"encoding":"hex"}` parameter (because this isn't mentioned in the documentation:

```
web3Utils.sha3("00000000000000000000000x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
```

But unfortunately, I still get the same output:

```
0x02d38ce98b8dae9d7cc32b64bb52580b4989cb56d07114b95037da4af5f500cf
```

The documentation mentions a `web3Utils.soliditySha3` function that sounded like it might do the trick, so I switched this function call in instead:

```
web3Utils.soliditySha3("00000000000000000000000x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", {"encoding":"hex"})
```

This time I got a different value, but it is not the one that I am looking for:

```
0x0780d226e6d7ac5576d20e78b8c3a2122ace468d419adefef1e79c49d7f4116f
```

I also tried removing the `{"encoding":"hex"}` parameter (because this also isn't mentioned in the documentation:

```
web3Utils.soliditySha3("00000000000000000000000x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
```

But this just results in the same, incorrect, value as the `web3Utils.sha3` function calls:

```
0x02d38ce98b8dae9d7cc32b64bb52580b4989cb56d07114b95037da4af5f500cf
```

I have also tried various permutations of the ["Any type, or an object with {type: 'uint', value: '123456'}"](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#id21) parameter format:

```
web3Utils.soliditySha3({type: 'string', value: "00000000000000000000000x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"})
```

And yet I still can't get the correct value.

**Does anyone know how to correctly address a mapping or struct storage address using the latest web3js library functions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the extra 'x' in the *key* and prefixing with '0x' it returns the same value in

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3();

const index = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
const key =   "00000000000000000000000090F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1";
const newKey =  web3.utils.sha3("0x" + key + index)
console.log(newKey)
```

> 0xbbf27a261d686d37ad5c6299e09a73a2a829c9c10eaf9c5c19e6ff2488e52f20